# Can't open host app from today extension

Tags: ios, swift

I've aded a button to my app widget. After reading some manuals and SO advises I've implemented what they wrote, but my action doesn't open host app. [Here's how I made in Info.plist of host app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9XQb.png)

And I made URL identifier both completely like the bundle identifier (com.ol.MyList) and just com.ol. Both didn't work.

And here's my action:

```
@IBAction func openHostApp() {
    if let url = URL(string: "localHost") {
        self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: {success in print("called url complete handler: \(success)")})
    }
}
```

It's compiled and doesn't crash, but completionHandler always return 'false' for 'success' parameter. What I made wrong and how to make it right?

I also want to add another button that opens host app and performs an action in there. How to implement that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open host app from **Today Extension**:

1.Add `URL Scheme` : `localHost` to host app's `URL Types`.

[image]

2.Code to open `host app` from `extension`,

```
   @IBAction func openHostApp()
{
    if let url = URL(string: "localHost://")
    {
        self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: {success in print("called url complete handler: \(success)")})
    }
}
```

Comment: But don't use 'localhost' as it's a bit generic and could clash with other apps if everyone copies this answer. You should come up with your own URL scheme, maybe relating to your bundle ID.

Comment: This was just an example. You need to use a more app specific URL scheme.